# How to configure the cache when using AFNetworking's setImageWithURL

Tags: objective-c, caching, ios5, afnetworking

I'm using `setImageWithURL` to download some images in my app. Is it possible:

1. to specify how long this image must be held in cache (eg 1 week)?
2. to specify how big the the maximum total size of the cache (eg 200
   MB)
3. to see what is in the image cache?
4. to clear the cache?

[The documentation](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/index.html) is not really clear on these points..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `UIImageView` category uses an internal, ephemeral cache for high performance in things like `UITableView`. For longer-term cache, use the system-level cacheing system--namely Peter Steinberger's fork of `SDURLCache`, a subclass of `NSURLCache`.

Set it up with the following code in the application delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`:

```
SDURLCache *URLCache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*2 diskCapacity:1024*1024*20 diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
[URLCache setIgnoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy:YES];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
[URLCache release];
```

Comment: Mattt. Can I disable cache only for particular url.

Comment: @MadNik `NSURLRequest` objects have a `cachePolicy` property, which you can set accordingly.