# Pre-cache Images for AFNetworking's UIImageView category

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurlcache

When my app loads, I pull down a JSON representation of 99 objects.

Each object has an 'image_url' field, which I pass to AFNetworking's `setImageWithURLRequest`.

My images load in a tableView, and consequently, only the first several cells make requests for their images. It's not until I scroll down that subsequent image requests are made.

Once I pull down the initial dataset, I'd like to be able to kick off a background process that goes out and downloads the 95 or so objects that aren't initially visible, and cache them in such a way that when `setImageWithURLRequest` is called, it'll already have a cached image to pull from.

AFImageCache is private though, so I'm not sure if this is possible. I know I could cache with NSURLCache, but then I'd have two separate, isolated caches, and that's not ideal either.

Is my only option to not use AFNetworking's UIImageView category?

These answers make me think so:

[iOS Caching images with AFImageCache doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469832/ios-caching-images-with-afimagecache-doesnt-seem-to-work)
[How to configure the cache when using AFNetworking's setImageWithURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433403/how-to-configure-the-cache-when-using-afnetworkings-setimagewithurl)

Comment: Caching 95 images to ram would take a lot of ram. If you do this please don't use the built in cache but build in a disk cache to the cache directory.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am caching the images onto disk. But when I am trying to load them from cache, sometimes they are not found. I asked the question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882639/how-should-i-pre-load-all-images-and-cache-them-using-afnetworking

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Please, *please* don't do this.**

Trust me when I say that this almost certainly unnecessary.

In fact, it will likely have the opposite of the desired effect, due to the increased pressure of downloading images that will probably never be viewed.

The cache is private for a very good reason--it's just there to speed up subsequent requests on scroll views. Just have the table view download the images as requested, and you should be just fine. If anything, you can optimize the size of the images that you are downloading (ensure correct image dimensions; compress intelligently).

Comment: How would I preload only the next 3 or 4 images?

Answer (score 5):

I would NOT create a bunch of UIImageView's to achieve your purpose, that would be a really inefficient approach.

You could add your own method to `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` to achieve this ability. I thin this would be the best approach. An untested example would be:

```
+ (void) cacheImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setHTTPShouldUsePipelining:YES];

    AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [[[self class] af_sharedImageCache] cacheImage:responseObject forRequest:request];
    } 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution - create some `UIImageView` objects (but don't add them as subviews) and then use AFNetworking's UIImageView category to fetch the images and populate its internal cache.

Sample Code:

```
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"http://i.imgur.com/IpQzE.png",
                    @"http://i.imgur.com/sDnLs.jpg",
                    nil];

for (NSString *string in strings) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
}
```

Comment: interesting. i actually had the same thought, but wasn't sure about the added overhead of all the UIImageViews I'd be creating. Is that not something I'd need to worry about? i'd be doing this with 100-500 images.

Comment: The memory usage of the UIImage objects will far outweigh that of the UIImageViews (especially if they are never added as subviews). Whatever strategy you end up using, you will have to carefully check its performance with Instruments on real hardware. You may trigger memory warnings downloading that many images, which will result in the image cache being cleared (check the documentation for NSCache)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to consider [Fully-Loaded](https://github.com/foursquare/fully-loaded/)

A simple self maintained cache is to download the images and save to a url dependent filename.

Whenever you want to load a image from a url, try read from harddisk first - if nil was returned, go ahead with your image downloader.

Do remember to clear your image caches though.